# The same set of public and private key encrypted text produces different types of variables?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cryptography, node-rsa

```
function encrypt(encrypted, publicKey) {
    const encrypt = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, Buffer.from(encrypted));
    return encrypt;
}
```

```
var ciphertext = this.encrypt("***",key.exportKey('public'))
```

Use the public and private keys generated by node rsa to encrypt using crypto and public key. How can I solve it?

[image]

I tried the conversion between uint8array and buffer, but it's different

Comment: The output should be available in the question as normal text, properly formatted. You can **additionally** include an image from an IDE if it adds clarity to the question. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: With nodejs you don't need `node-rsa` to generate RSA keypair, see `crypto.generateKeyPair[Sync]`. Your question isn't very clear and isn't reproducible at all, but if you are expecting different executions of 'standard' RSA encryption (RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5) or OAEP (the default for `crypto.publicEncrypt`) of the same data with the same keypair to produce the same cryptogram/ciphertext, it doesn't.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Vue and Node default to different types when dealing with binary data. After using toString to transfer the data, the string can be converted to a buffer on the Node side. I'm sorry, this is my first time on this forum and I behaved very foolishly. I apologize.Thank you very much for your answer. Have a good day.